# Role Hierarchy Changes Analysis

Tags: role-hierarchy

I have been asked to assess role hierarchy changes.  I am thinking that analysis of the sharing rules, public groups, reports, user management and data movement are areas to consider.

Anyone have advice on this type of task - I would greatly appreciate it!

K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you go through the [Force.com Fundamentals Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf) for creating a Recruiting Application. A role hierarchy is  created as part of creating the application. The criteria that you'll want to consider when creating roles vs an existing organization's functional structure is explained in a fair amount of detail in the section that covers it.

Sharing groups, sharing rules, determining OWD, FLS, reports and user management are also covered as well. This workbook is the basis of most of what one needs to know to pass the DEV-401 Certification. Your question is far too broad to answer beyond pointing you to this workbook and telling you to spend the time that's necessary to work your way through it. When you have a more specific question, feel free to come back and ask it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the direction.  Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Thanks for posting on SFSE. Community etiquette is to upvote well thought out questions and answers if you have sufficient reputation plus help the rest of the community by marking posts as solving your question if they helped you resolve your issue.